# VirtualBox Ubuntu - Mouse only works on left sidebar

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

My mouse does only work in the left sidebar, but it fails completly outside of it.

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Install Ubuntu Guest Extensions, try a different mouse. I have an Ubuntu 22.04 VM in VMware and mouse works fine.

Comment: Already installed and same with another mouse.

Comment: Try spinning up a new Ubuntu machine and see if there was an error in the old machine.

Comment: Thats already my second machine, first one failed too. First it always work fine, but then after a few restarts it does not work anymore.

Comment: I am running out of ideas.  I have had Ubuntu running for a long time and mice work fine (long time). Try reinstalling Virtual Box and see if the helps.

Comment: Also consider a trial of VMware to see if that solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

It happens to me if Shared Clipboard is enabled (Settings / General / Advanced). Try setting this to "Disabled" and reboot the guest system.